# When to repaint the entire UI of a game (without making it slow on low devices)

Tags: android, game-engine, game-physics, frame-rate

I'm developing a game which consists in some views on the screen that are being moved and you can interact with them.

I'm modifying the x,y and the width and heigh of those views using ObjectAnimator.

I'm adding more views and removing some of the views and adding them again each X seconds with new coordinates and new scales.

For update the screen I'm invalidating each 10 milliseconds the entire collection of items on screen with this run method on a thread:

```
   public void run() {
       while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
           synchronized(this){      
               wait(10);            
               doSomeStuffInOtherThread(); //like adding more items or moving them, etc...
               allMyObjects.invalidateInOtherThread(); //this is just pseudocode for simplify the sample
           }
       }
   }
```

It works, on powerful devices the items are being repainted each 10 ms and it gives the user a smooth framerate sensation. The problem is that when I test the game on low devices, the game is very slow. I think that it is because the methods doSomeStuffInOtherThread() and allMyObjects.invalidate()InOtherThread takes too much to execute on low devices, more than 10ms, and on high end devices it is done instantly (in less than 10ms).

Is there a better way to repaint the screen without losing game speed? If the game is losing fps it's not a problem, The problem is that it is losing speed.

Comment: What do you mean "losing speed" ? Maybe using the elapsed time since the last frame in your computations would do it.

Comment: @Zouch i mean that if i'm moving the objects on a powerful device, they move very fast, if i move them in a low end device, they move very slow. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that in lower devices 10ms is not enought to calculate the stuff of those two functions. Please, explain your proposal, I can't figure what are you trying to tell me

Comment: You should [read this](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/). I will elaborate later !

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your problem is that you rely on the time your device will take to process your stuff. This could be illustrated with something similar

```
struct Ball {
    float pos_x, pos_y;
    float vel_x, vel_y;
};

int main() {
    Ball b{ 0.f, 0.f, 10.f, 10.f };

    for (;;) {
        DosomethingThatMightTakeAWhile();
        b.pos_x += b.vel_x;
        b.pos_y += b.vel_y;
    }
}
```

Looking at this simple piece of code, you can easily see that any computer will take 10 steps to go from `(0, 0)` to `(100, 100)`, but depending on the time `DoSomethingThatMightTakeAWhile()` takes to finish on a particular computer, those 10 steps might be completed in 10 milliseconds as well as in 10 seconds. And this is your problem here. You do not take the actual time spent doing the computations to compute how much your elements move.

To fix this, you simply need to take the time elapsed since the last frame into account (and maybe sleep for a bit of time to save the battery). So now your code will look like this

```
int main() {
    Ball b{ 0.f, 0.f, vel_x, vel_y }; // vel_x and vel_y are the new velocities,
                                      // tweaked to match the speed you want

    int64_t t0, t1; // In milliseconds here
    t0 = GetTimeSinceStartup();

    for (;;) {
        DoSomethingThatMightTakeAWhile();

        t1 = GetTimeSinceStartup();
        float dt = (t1 - t0) / 1000.f;  // Time elapsed in seconds
        t0 = t1;

        b.pos_x += b.vel_x * dt;
        b.pos_y += b.vel_y * dt;
    }
}
```

You can see that the code is not much more complicated, but the difference is that, now, you effectively take the time elapsed into account when you compute your new position. That means that the time `DoSomethingThatMightTakeAWhile()` does not really matter anymore, if you want your ball to take 1 second to move by 100 pixels, you set it's speed to 100 pixels per second, and it will take 1 second.